# Can't set window size under VT100 emulation

Tags: command-line, resize

I tried to run `resize 40 80` to change my terminal display and got the following error:

`Can't set window size under VT100 emulation`

Can anyone explain what causes this issue and how to bypass?

Comment: Apologies, I have updated it. I didn't think the size was important - every size is broke.

Comment: sometimes people using parameters incorrectly so seeing exactly what is typed helps. I've posted an answer based on your preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
$ resize 40 80
resize: Can't set window size under VT100 emulation
```

Try using:

```
printf '\e[8;40;80t'
```

You can also use `Edit` -> `Profile preferences` and set the initial screen size every time your terminal opens.

Comment: The command printf '\e[8;40;80t' worked perfectly and elongated the terminal. I'm still concerned about why the 'resize' command will not work. Do you have any explanation? see it used to before, I have changed no settings and now it does not work so I am wondering what has happened. Thanks for your help, cool trick!

Comment: The `resize` command woks in `xterm` terminal windows. We use gnome-terminal windows which requires VT100 commands. The `printf '\e[8;40;80t'` is a command for VT100 terminal emulators. You can use commands for changing color too: `printf '%b\n' 'It is \033[31mnot\033[39m intelligent to use \033[32mhardcoded ANSI\033[39m codes!'`